# How can I get the SVN URL by giving committed file name and the svn revision?

Tags: batch-file, svn

I am trying to get the SVN URL by passing the filename and the revision of commit.

How can I get the SVN URL by giving the committed file name and the svn revision as input in a batch script?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Batch file input `set /p varName=Prompt"`, common command-line calling method: `program arg1 arg2`

Comment: This question page is so full of failure I doubt it will ever get a worthwhile answer.  Vague question with no explanation of SVN's URL composition, no code or demonstration of any effort, a useless edit that adds nothing, a random comment showing code that seems completely unrelated to the question, and someone upvoted this question as useful for some reason.  Rani, please read the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) FAQ page.  I'm voting to close this steaming pile of futility for now.  I may retract my vote if Rani edits the question.